# How to set skype advanced connection Options on fedora 19

Tags: linux, fedora, skype

I have switched from Ubuntu 12.10 (mint nadia(14) cinnamon) to fedora 19 (gnome). So far so good. I installed skype via the fedorautils.  Now that I am testing it using a Vodafone usb modem, it doesn't seem to connect.

I failed to see where i could set the options.I mean at least the connection bit where I can verify that it's set on automatic proxy detection or set it to it.

Maybe because of the gnome look and feel I am a bit lost about how to set it.

Thanks for your help